# Defining a "macro" in HTML?

Tags: html

In LaTeX, we can define a macro so that we don't have to keep typing the same thing all the time.

For my website, which is HTML + CSS, I'm constantly repeating a custom "separator": `&ensp;/&ensp;`.

Can I define a macro so that it expands to this string?

Surprised to have found nothing online about this. I guess it's because "macro" means a different thing in HTML?

Comment: Yes, it's called JavaScript. HTML is a static markup language meant to convey semantics. You are asking for the language to do something other than what it is designed to do. CSS is strictly for presentation. JavaScript is for programming behavior. All 3 of these languages work together to create web applications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a fundamental misunderstanding of what HTML is.

Comment: With HTML: no. With anything that can *generate* HTML: sure.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the nice explanations of HTML, CSS, and JS! But regarding closing this question, isn't one of this site's goals to clear misunderstandings for language novices?

Comment: No, it’s not. Stack Overflow isn’t a tutorial site or a place for generalized questions. We expect that you will do exhaustive research on your own before you post. And, when you do post, it should be a specific question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorry but I can't agree with you on that. When a newbie learns a new language, sometimes he/she wouldn't know what the correct keywords are. Like in this case, I wouldn't even know what keywords to use for my "exhaustive research." The best I could was searching "macros in html," but as I said the returned results are useless due to the incorrect keywords. This is where SO comes useful -- I can use my natural language to describe my problem, and get corrected with the proper keywords, with which I can then do research myself.

Comment: With respect Sibbs, it's not about whether you agree or not.Stack Overflow is not a platform to do basic research on. Taking the time to learn web development, would answer your question and there are many platforms and places to do that research. Please read our ["How to ask a question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you'll see the first thing we ask if that you search and search and then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use SGML entities, but it is not a standard compliant solution and it only works when serving the file as XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html [
  <!ENTITY name "John">
  <!ENTITY surname "Doe">
  <!ENTITY fullname "&name; &surname;">
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head><title>Test</title></head>
  <body>Hello, my name is &fullname;.</body>
</html>
```

As already noticed in other comments, use something else like JavaScript or XSLT.

Comment: You say it is not standards compliant, but add a title element to the document, and [it will pass the validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Falohci.net%2Fapplication%2Fxhtml%2Bxml%2Fentities.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks both! @Alohci does this mean this is a standard compliant solution?

Comment: @SibbsGambling - I'm prepared to take the validator's word for it, so I think so. The HTML5 spec doesn't say anything in the [XML syntax section](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/xhtml.html#the-xhtml-syntax) that leads me to believe otherwise. It does warn against trying to use entities from an external DTD, but nothing against using them within the XHTML file.

Comment: Hmmm, as a front-end newbie, can I check if the `DOCTYPE` is properly closed in the snippet above? From the format highlighting, it seems unclosed. The trailing `]>` also shows up as contents in my HTML render. (Happy Thanksgiving!)

Comment: It is invalid HTML, but valid X(H)TML. If you want it to render correctly as local file, call the file `example.xml`.